# Android how to identify item in listview with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, textview, imageview

I am really stuck here. What I want is not simple (for me), however I've been programming android a year now.
What I want is a listview with an imageview, a textview, a checkbox, and another textview in each row.
Let's have a textview and a checkbox first in the layout.
Based on [this](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php) tutorial I managed to do that (there are a lot, but this seems to be the best for me). I have a listview populated with textviews and checkboxes.

This is the result:

[image]

This is how I get the text of textview I click on:

```
 textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v ;
            String text_of_clicked_textview = tv.getText().toString();
            Log.i("TAG", "" + text_of_clicked_textview);
        }
    });
```

So When I click on Mercury, I get *Mercury* in the text_of_clicked_textview variable.

But how can i check which checkbox I clicked on? E.g I click on the 3rd checkbox, I want to now it is in the row of Earth. Best would be if I get to know both the text of textview in the row of the listview(*Earth*) and and number of the item (*3*).

I guess I have to set an onClickListener on the checkbox but what next?

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;

      }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is XML for Custom Row in ListView :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/camera_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" 
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is Complete Activity in which List is implemented :
Just Copy this Activity for test then understand code. Place one listview in main Activity

```
package com.DemoTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<EachRow> list=new ArrayList<CustomList.EachRow>();
    EachRow each;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] color={"red","green","blue","white","yellow","cyan","purple","grey",
                "0red","0green","0blue","0white","0yellow","0cyan","0purple","0grey",
                "1red","1green","1blue","1white","1yellow","1cyan","1purple","1grey"};
        for(String str : color)
        {
            each=new EachRow();
            each.text=str;
            list.add(each);
        }
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 0, list)); 
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EachRow>
    {
        LayoutInflater inflat;
        ViewHolder holder;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<EachRow> objects) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflat=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_checkox, null);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.check=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.check.setOnClickListener(CustomList.this);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            EachRow row= getItem(position);
            Log.d("size", row.text);
            holder.textView.setText(row.text); 
            holder.check.setChecked(row.checkBool); 
            holder.check.setTag(position);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public EachRow getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        private class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textView;
            ImageView image;
            CheckBox check;
        }
    }
    private class EachRow
    {
        String text;
        boolean checkBool;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        EachRow row=list.get((Integer)v.getTag());
         row.checkBool=!row.checkBool;
         Log.d("item", "Item Click at "+(Integer)v.getTag()+" : "+row.text+" is "+row.checkBool); 
    }

}
```

Comment: u find it useful ! great.U can make one up for it :)

Comment: @Pankaj can you help me with this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045149/setting-image-resourse-by-obtaining-tag-position-for-an-imageview-android

Answer (score 1):

Better than adding an onClickListener to each checkbox, you could also use an ItemClickListener on your list.

Refer to this post to find out the row that has been clicked : 
[onItemClick <string-array> strings.xml (not ListView/ArrayList)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444184/onitemclick-string-array-strings-xml-not-listview-arraylist)

There are other options, but it involves creating a custom row widget class, and passing it its row position when your adapter creates or updates it.

Comment: When user clicks on the textview (which is the whole row, because cb is set android:layout_alignParentRight="true"), a new activity should be opened. But when user clicks on the checkbox, I have to know which checkbox they clicked on. So ItemClickListener is not a good option, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, erdomester is right. When u have checkbox in listview row(Custom Row) check box takes a focus.See the code below is the solution

Answer (score 0):

you would have to have a onTouchListener on the container that holds all of them and make sure that you return false on your listeners so that they don't consume the event. onClickListener consumes it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you only concerned with text and checkbox then you can use this

In XML :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewCursor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >

String[] color={"red","green","blue","white","yellow","cyan","purple","grey"};

list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, color));
```

ANd on some event check which checkboxes are selected.

```
SparseBooleanArray boolArray=list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int size=list.getCount();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(boolArray.valueAt(i)==true)
            {
                Log.d("size", color[i]);
            }
        }
```