# onItemClick <string-array> strings.xml (not ListView/ArrayList)

Tags: android, arrays

I have a  on strings.xml file.  All the entries are showen a on ListView, and now i want to make a treatement on evey item touch/click.
I have righted this code:

```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>        
>         
>         setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
>                 R.array.tut_titles, R.layout.offresaffichage));
>         
>     }
>     
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                 int position, long id) {
>           final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tut_titles);
// what to do here?
```

How to retrieve item position on the  and start another activity from it?
I thinked about switch, case but don't know how implement it.
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second int of your parameter list in the onItemClick method :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tut_titles);
   String link = links[ position ];
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
   i.setData(Uri.parse( link ));  
   startActivity(i);          
}//met
```

Comment: In that case, how it will know that this onitemClick is for the <string-array> ? this code is "independent". ?

Comment: I have some strings in the string.xml file as <string-array>, i have adapted this strings on a listview and they are well showen, in cons, i don't know how to manipulate that strings, when i tap on one of them i have a triggered intent. Hope that this is more clear now :)

Comment: nope. Sorry. But I believe you have everything you need. you don't have to care about what's in the string at which row, just wonder how to react whedn this or that row is clicked.

Comment: Exactly, don't know how to react when an item on <srting-array> is clicked. Anyway, i'll return to listview+ arraylist. Wanted to have things more simple and more clear :/.

Comment: look at my post, I edited it, maybe this will suit your needs

Comment: `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tut_titles);
        String link = links[ position ];
        if (link=="Food")
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
            
        }`

Comment: but you don't thing that i have to implement a listener ?

Comment: you should put that code into an inner class that implements OnItemClickListener, then instanciate this inner class and register it on the list view using lv.setOnItemClickListener( new <your inner class>);