# Android listview with sql skips _ character

Tags: android, sql, listview

I have a listview populated from an sql table. I am not sharing the add new record and the query function since they are working fine. Steps:

1. User creates a new record in an edittext: easy rider
2. Table is created: easy_rider (using `newlist_listname.replaceAll(" ","_");`)
3. List is populated with the new record: easyrider (where is the _ mark??)
4. A new table is also created: easy_rider (and yes this is still good)

I get the result of the sql into a cursor and then into ArrayLists:

```
     c = info.getAllTitles();
             if (c.moveToFirst())
             {
             do{
                todoItems.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2) + " " + c.getString(3) +  " " + c.getString(4) + " " + c.getString(5));
                todoItemsID.add(c.getString(0));
                todoItemsNAME.add(c.getString(1));
                todoItemsPRIORITY.add(c.getString(2));
                todoItemsFINISHED.add(c.getString(3));
                todoItemsNOTES.add(c.getString(4));
                todoItemsHIDDEN.add(c.getString(5));
                }while (c.moveToNext());
             }

 if (todoItemsNAME.size() >= 0)
             {
                 for (int i=0; i<todoItemsNAME.size(); i++)
                 {
                     Log.d("todoItemsNAME(" + i + ")", todoItemsNAME.get(i) + ""); //easy_rider
                 }
             }
```

Population:

```
     if (todoItems.size() >= 0)
         {
             for (int i=0; i<todoItems.size(); i++)
             {
                 Log.d("TODOItems(" + i + ")", todoItems.get(i) + "");  //27 easy_rider Low 1 1
                 each=new EachRow();
                 each.text= todoItemsNAME.get(i);
                 Log.d("each.text", each.text); //easy_rider
                 list.add(each);
             }
             listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 1, list)); 
         }
```

Everything seems to be good here. I get easy_rider everywhere except in the list. WHY?
Same result when I enter easy_rider as new record. I see easyrider in the list.

The base of the whole code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox/9445227#9445227) thanks to Pankaj:

```
public class CustomList extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<EachRow> list=new ArrayList<CustomList.EachRow>();
    EachRow each;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] color={"red","green","blue","white","yellow","cyan","purple","grey",
                "0red","0green","0blue","0white","0yellow","0cyan","0purple","0grey",
                "1red","1green","1blue","1white","1yellow","1cyan","1purple","1grey"};
        for(String str : color)
        {
            each=new EachRow();
            each.text=str;
            list.add(each);
        }
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 0, list)); 
        //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EachRow>
    {
        LayoutInflater inflat;
        ViewHolder holder;
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<EachRow> objects) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflat=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=inflat.inflate(R.layout.row_checkox, null);
                holder=new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                holder.check=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.check.setOnClickListener(CustomList.this);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            EachRow row= getItem(position);
            Log.d("size", row.text);
            holder.textView.setText(row.text); 
            holder.check.setChecked(row.checkBool); 
            holder.check.setTag(position);
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public EachRow getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        private class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView textView;
            ImageView image;
            CheckBox check;
        }
    }
    private class EachRow
    {
        String text;
        boolean checkBool;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        EachRow row=list.get((Integer)v.getTag());
         row.checkBool=!row.checkBool;
         Log.d("item", "Item Click at "+(Integer)v.getTag()+" : "+row.text+" is "+row.checkBool); 
    }

}
```

**Here if I add gr een or 0bl_ue, listview shows gr een and 0bl_ue. So the problem is in my code.** And it must be the list or the listview since when I click on the row I get easy_rider in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your font type, maybe you just dont see the underscore. Some font types are tricky :)

Comment: You were right, the space is almost invisible at this font type.