# List View shows objects instead of rows in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I have  to generate a list view with each row having an icon and a name. The code looks something like this.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
...
...

    ArrayList<StringBuilder> categories = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    categories.add(new StringBuilder("xyaq"));
    categories.add(new StringBuilder("wers"));
    categories.add(new StringBuilder("test2"));
    categories.add(new StringBuilder("asfda"));
    categories.add(new StringBuilder("hoyio"));

    ArrayList<RelativeLayout> departments = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();

    for (StringBuilder category : categories) {
        RelativeLayout categoryRow = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.products_row, null);

        ImageView tempImage = (ImageView) categoryRow.getChildAt(0);
        tempImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        TextView tempTextView = (TextView) categoryRow.getChildAt(1);
        tempTextView.setText(category);
        departments.add(categoryRow);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<RelativeLayout> departmentAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<RelativeLayout>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, departments);

    setListAdapter(departmentAdaptor);
}
```

and the products_row.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/deptIcon"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deptName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/deptIcon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem I am facing is I cannot see the rows with an image and the corresponding text. Instead it shows the list of relative layout objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct way to do what you are trying to achieve.
You need to create you custom adapter for this.

See this link and check my answer :
[Listview with Image,Text and Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox/9445227#comment11951657_9445227)

There is whole Activity code and contains an innerclass MyAdapter that extends ArrayAdapte.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pankaj. Creating a custom adapter did the trick! But I am curious to know why didn't my way of implementation(passing an arraylist of list row to arrayadapter) work? :-)

Comment: It does not assign Relative from ArrayList to our listview automatically.We have to assign data to components manually.That is the way listview works