# Displaying multiple Items in simple_list_item_1

Tags: java, android

I followed this guide http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html and altered the table and code to handle additional fields. But when the list is displayed it only displays the Item field and not the price. I can't find where in the code it does this.

Here is the code for the loading of items into the adapter, the getAllItems returns and array of items. Item has id, item and price.

```
    List<Item> values = datasource.getAllItems();

    // Use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the
    // elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the code behind that :

```
        public List<Item> getAllItems() {


            List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
            Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_ITEMS,
                    null, null, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Item item = cursorToItem(cursor);
                items.add(item);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // Make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return items;
        }

        private Item cursorToItem(Cursor cursor) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            item.setItem(cursor.getString(1));
            item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
            return item;
        }
```

It appears 'values' is only Item.items and not price and ID but I don't see why?

Comment: You'll need to make your own class that extends ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method to pull out both data pieces and put them each into their own View.

Answer (score 0):

Without the whole private Item cursorToItem stuff, how about adding

```
     while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                   items.add(cursor.getLong(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(1));               
  cursor.moveToNext(); 
                }
```

If you want to have more objects in a row, your task is much bigger. I suggest you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox/9445227#comment11957714_9445227) link and implement Pankaj's code. I have been using it for a while and it works like a charm. However, it took me a while to understand.