# How to manipulate data in list view that is populated by custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have populated a list view using the custom cursor adapter, That listview consists of a `checkbox` and `button` in the below manner.

```
checkbox1 button1
checkbox2 button2
.
.
.
```

Now I want to navigate to another activity when click on the button in list view now my issue here is when I click on the `button1` then I want to see the data in checkbox1 and similarly for other rows as well.

Now I am confused on how to maintain a `sync` between the checkbox and button and how to achieve the click functionality. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following on the `Button`'s `onClickListener` if the `Button` and `CheckBox` share the same parent

```
boldButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
       View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
       CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) parentView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    }
});
```

This will give you the `CheckBox` corresponding to the clicked `Button`

Comment: Hi Approv... sorry for replying late on answer couldn't get time... Actually I tried only button click listener that is present in list view but not as you suggested.. can you please advice me whether it is correct approach. thanks

Comment: You have to set the above mentioned `onClickListener` in `getView` on the `Button`

Comment: Yes I have done same.... I am confused whether it is a correct approach or not.. I will continue if you advice me wheter it is a correct approach also please edit your answer so that I can accept it as answered.

Comment: yeah it is the correct approach...what problem are you facing?

Comment: There is no problem assuch but as a newbie to android just want to know whether the followed approach is correct or not. Thanks for confirming. As I asked you if you can edit the answer I will mark it as answered

Comment: i will need to see your `getView` method to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find your corresponding view in the list view implementing the onclickListener

For eg

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
                            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                  Intent i=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.Class)
                                   startActivity(i);    
                           }
            });
                            //Similarly for the checkbox
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Shink but this is onclick for listview but I want to click the button in listview to navigate to new activity then how to achive the button click in list view

Comment: Inside the listview's onclick implement button's onclick and navigate...check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ViewHolder` class in adapter class and use that in `getView()`, Then within `getView`

```
viewHolder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(viewHolder.checkbox.isChecked())
                                // toggle the check and do your work here
        }
    });
```

You can learn `ViewHolder` pattern [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) its very simple

Another example [link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: Thanks @Viswanath viewholder should be attached to listview or button?

Comment: Viewholder should be attached to each listitem  , You can see that in the provided link

Answer (score 0):

This [Selectable ListView Tutorial](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-tutorials-custom-selectable-listview) link should help in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post might help.
You have to preserve the state of row in listview so row can be populated with its state.

> [Android how to identify item in listview with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox/9445227#9445227)