# ListView - differentiate between a checkbox selection and a text selection

Tags: android, android-listview

Given the ListView below, I wanted to perform two different actions depending on whether the user selects the text (create a new activity) or clicks the associated checkbox (add it to a favorites list). Is this possible in with this setup or will I have to use a custom adapter or even a different layout?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>


setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, teams));
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String team_name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().trim();
                Intent intent = new Intent("blah.blah.blah");
                intent.putExtra("team", team_name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
});
```

A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, your ListView should contain TextBox and CheckBox and TextBox and CheckBox are clickable, not ListView itself.

For this you have to  make custom adapter, where you will make listeners for both the TextBox and CheckBox.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // your_costum_view should contain textbox and checkboc
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_costum_view, null);

        // Get your checkbox and textbox and add listeners
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setOnClickListener...

        Checkbox checkbox=(CheckBox)view.findById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener...


        return view;
    }

}
```

your_costum_view layout example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom adapter will help you keep trace of your views, it will be easier than use a default adapter that you can't control. For references: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom adapter will definitely make your life easier. In the adapter you can make reference to both the checkbox and the textView and add an `onClick` Listener to each - from there you can also add code to handle each event. I would also suggest using a recyclerView instead of a ListView. It is the new thing in Android 5.0 and it really is easier to use then a regular ListView. Hope this helps:
[RecyclerView Help](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the CheckBox as focusable="false" in your XML layout.

```
android:focusable="false"
```

if don't run go [to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444165/android-how-to-identify-item-in-listview-with-checkbox) and see example because you need a create custom row in list view and set:

```
Checkbox checkbox=(CheckBox)view.findById(R.id.checkboxID);
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //do stuff

        }
    });
```