# Setting image resourse by obtaining tag position for an imageview android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am making use of recycler view. I have a layout that is highlighted in light red,this layout is included for each item in the recycler view. The light red layout is placed over the background image. I am using setTag method to identify the clicks of the buttons in red layout. That is working properly when i click i get the position. The problem is i want to change the image at specific position. 
For example : Consider the heart button. I have set a tag on it like this.

**heartButton = findViewById(id);
heartButton.setTag(position);**

now i get the position by using the getTag method. But now i want to change the image of the heartButton at the a specific position. Is there something like

**heartButton.getTag(position).setImageResouce(drawable);**

If not how do i do this then.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a custom click listener and updated the like in the setter getter.But this works only when the view has been moved out of the view (i think it is the scrapeview)

The Setter Getter Class

```
public class DemoData {

    int background;
    boolean liked;

    public DemoData(int background) {
        this.background = background;
    }

    public int getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

//    public void setBackground(int background) {
//        this.background = background;
//    }

    public boolean isLiked() {
        return liked;
    }

    public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
        this.liked = liked;
    }
}
```

The onBindViewHolder function of the recycler view

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        background = (ImageView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        layout = (LinearLayout) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        delete = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        lock = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.lock);


        delete.setTag("delete_"+position);
        lock.setTag("lock_"+position);

        if(Constants.demoDatas.get(position).isLiked()){
            delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        else{
            delete.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
        }

        delete.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener(position));
        lock.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener(position));



    }
```

The custom click listener is as below

```
public class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int position;


    public CustomClickListener(int position) {

        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        String identifier[] = tag.split("_");

        // this line saves my state in the Setter Getter Class
        Constants.demoDatas.get(position).setLiked(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution works fine but the images dont update immediately and get updated only once we scroll the recyclerView.
Anyone knows about this ???

Comment: Sagar, above solution is same as my asnwer,only add notify dataset changed after setLiked() and its done

Answer (score 1):

use `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.XXX)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: i still didnt get it. A code snippet or example would be great.

Comment: `heartButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.XXX)`

method `setTag()` and `getTag()` is used to find `View` in `ViewContainer` or `ViewGroup`. You don't need to use it here

Comment: what if i want to change the imageResource of the heartbutton at the position 3 how do i do it then? I am not getting your answer

Comment: you have to find the exact heartButton. For searching `View` (one heartButton) by tag you can use `findViewWithTag("tag")` method (static method of `View` class). But be careful, tag must be unique.

When you find that one `View` (one heartButton) you call `setBackgroundResource()` method on it.

Comment: since i had four buttons heart arrow share and call

Comment: I have set the tag for all the four buttons (heart , arrow, share , dial) like this, so for zero all the four buttons have the same tag similarly for 1, 2 ,3 etc


heart.setTag(position);
arrow.setTag(position);
share.setTag(position);
dial.setTag(position);

now i am finding the id like this 
ImageView iv = like.findViewWithTag(position);
iv.setImageResource(drawable);

For this i am getting a null pointer exception at iv. What am i doing wrong here

Comment: like I said tag must be unique, so try to set tag like this: for heart use `heart.setTag("heart_" + position);`, for arrow use `arrow.setTag("arrow_" + position)` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69214/discussion-between-sagar-devanga-and-eldest).

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to do this is,
You have to keep the state of the heart button stored in the model(POJO) which is passed to custom adapter.
e.g.

```
class ModelListItem{
public static final int HEART=1,BROKEN_HEART=2;

int heartButtonState;

}
```

Now in onClick() of heart button, get that object from adapter using position,cosidering you have already figured it out on how to preserve position from heart button

```
ModelListItem item = (ModelListItem)adapter.getItem(position)
```

Change the state of heart button;

```
item.setHeartButtonState(ModelListItem.BROKEN_HEART);
   adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

You already know below explaination but just in case
To work this properly,in your getView methode of adapter you need to put the check on heartButtonState(); and use appropriate image resource.

```
getView(BOILERPLATE){
 BOILERPLATE

 switch(item.getheartButtonState()){
 case ModelItemList.HEART:
   heartbutton.setImageResource(heart_image);
 break;
 case ModelItemList.BROKEN_HEART:
   heartbutton.setImageResource(broken_heart_image);
 break;  
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't find getItem() in Recycler's Adapter